# JQuery Slider выделяется пунктиром при нажатии в браузере

Tags: html, jquery

При выборе диапазона с помощью слайдера остаётся выделение объекта в виде пунктира. Пропадает при нажатии на другую часть страницы. Как можно отключить это выделение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input {outline: 0 !important;}

:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```

Можно и скомпоновать, на любителя